# What is Relator Matrix

Tags: finite-groups, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, computational-algebra

At the third section of a paper "Computing second cohomology of finite groups with trivial coefficients" by G. Ellis et al., the authors write

***Suppose that $<\underline{x}\mid \underline{r}>=<x_1 \cdots x_d \mid r_1 \cdots r_m>$ is the presentation of the finite group $G$, so that $\underline{x}$ is a generating set for $F$ and $\underline{r}$ is a set of elements in $F$ that normally generate $R$. The function RelatorMatrix(F,rels), with rels := $\underline{r}$, uses the LLL algorithm to return integer matrices $B,T$.***

In the above $F$ is free group such that $F/R=G$.

I have searched many times in google what is Relator matrix with integer coefficient. How to find integer matrix with given presentation. I find nothing. I will be thankful to you if you kindly tell me how to find these matrices or tell me the reference where I can find these.

Comment: [Here](http://hamilton.nuigalway.ie/software/SecondCohomology.magma) is the algorithm for RelatorMatrix in MAGMA.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I will be thankful to you if you kindly explain what these commands are doing. I would like to calculate cohomology and Schur Multiplier of some small groups manually. I would like to understand why this is working. I know GAP but dont know MAGMA. Also while searching for LLL algorithm I found (in Wikipedia) that it will one matrix. Why LLL(M) is giving two matrices B and T in that code.